# "Irrelevant for" vs. "irrelevant to"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adjectives

Reading some of the comments on StackExhange, I came across

> this is irrelevant for this question

Shouldn't it be "irrelevant *to* this question"? Searching on Google I found both are used in various academic texts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer *irrelevant to*, but certainly accept *irrelevant for*:

- Noun phrase: *This is irrelevant to (for) the matter at hand*
- Gerund: *This is irrelevant to (for) resolving the matter at hand*
- Personal pronoun: *This is irrelevant to (for) me*

However, when the complement is preposed, I prefer *for* over *to*:

- Noun phrase: *For/?to the matter at hand, this is irrelevant*
- Gerund: *For/??to resolving the matter at hand, this is irrelevant*
- Personal pronoun: *For/to me, this is irrelevant*

—though note that *to me* in the last sentence means *to my mind* (*To me, this is irrelevant* doesn't seem to mean what *This is irrelevant to me* does)

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you quite easily could've resisted, actually.

Comment: @Daniel: +100, seriously

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your time. We should probably correct spelling mistakes this way.

Comment: @Noah Now that you've removed them, my comment doesn't make sense.  Ah well, better that it's corrected, though.

Comment: @Noah Serious answer now posted.

Comment: @DanielHarbour Your original "answer" should have been just that—a comment.

Comment: @Mahnax You're probably right, though it did contain a proper response parenthetically.

Answer (score 4):

Although, mostly, "irrelevant to" is the correct phrase, it is sometimes used interchangeably with "irrelevant for". I couldn't find many examples where "irrelevant for" has been used (and in these examples, "irrelevant for" can be conveniently replaced by "irrelevant to").
[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing the source of two images you posted?

Answer (score 0):

This is my own interpretation.

I would use "for" when there is intentionality, something depends on this thing being relevant to the issue in question. For example, "Here the specific conditions are irrelevant *for* the kind of problem the puzzle is meant to pose." But it wouldn't make much sense to say that "His music has become irrelevant for the present young audiences."